# Angular 2 load router outlet after event ready

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I need to load my router outlet after loading some data from local .json files as the content depends on the data. So this is what the template of my app component looks like:

```
<div *ngIf="data_ready">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div *ngIf="data_ready">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <list-view></list-view>
    </div>

</div>
```

The problem is, that my root `/` redirects me to `/overview` which then loads the first component to use in my router. Since I don't have any router outlet available because of the asynchronous data loading the error message indicating that there is no `<router-outlet>` on init, is pretty clear.

The question is whether there is a way to make the routing work though the router-outlet is just available milliseconds after the initialization.

Comment: What do you mean by "load my router outlet"?

Comment: Sorry that was my fault, I updated the question in order to make it more understandable. As you may see right now, the router-outlet is enclosed by a ngIf which renders the router outlet after the data_ready variable turns true. In that case I'm going to receive an error that there is no available outlet when accessing the route leading to the route rendering (which makes total sense). The main problem is that everything within the router-outlet needs the data which is loaded ansynchronous.

Comment: As far as I know wrapping a router-outlet with `*ngIf` doesn't work currently. Use `[hidden]` instead for example. I think this was fixed already in master (not sure).

Comment: Changing *ngIf with [hidden] worked for me. Thanks a lot!
I found though a more "Angular" way to do it:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard